# Batch Data-driven variables automatically size text to fit a defined area

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-scripting, illustrator-scripting

so I want to know if it's possible to generate text on image 
with fixed width and adjust the text to fit the full width if, for example, the variable name length is short.
Example in attachment
I hope it's clear.
Thanks in advance
[image: example image]

Comment: Yes but what have you tried and what is your level of expertise

Comment: @joojaa my level of expertise is very limited I'm just able to make work the Automating Variables and Data Sets process but can't figure out how to deal with the different length of text on names variable to fit the entire area each time